# OCaml Makefile stops working after a small modification

Tags: makefile, ocaml

I wish to compile my OCaml code with a Makefile at the root of the repository, this code is in another repository named `step1`. But for some reason, by simply adding the sources path the compilation does not work anymore?

Here is my Makefile:

```
DIR     = step1

SRC     = $(DIR)/door.ml\
        $(DIR)/tile.ml\
        $(DIR)/maze.ml\
        $(DIR)/display.ml\
        $(DIR)/main.ml

OCAMLFLAGS = -w Aelz -warn-error A -g

all: step1 step1.byte

step1:  step1.native
        cp $< $@

step1.byte: $(SRC)
        ocamlc $(OCAMLFLAGS) $^ -o $@

step1.native: $(SRC)
        ocamlopt $(OCAMLFLAGS) $^ -o $@

clean:
        $(RM) *.cmo *.cmi *.o *.cmx

fclean: clean
        $(RM) step1 step1.byte step1.native step2 step2.native step2.byte step3 step3.native step3.byte step4 step4.byte step4.native step5 step5.byte step5.native

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all clean fclean re
```

The error message I get is as follows:

```
 ocamlopt -w Aelz -warn-error A -g step1/door.ml step1/tile.ml step1/maze.ml step1/display.ml step1/main.ml -o step1.native
File "step1/tile.ml", line 1, characters 0-9:
Error: Unbound module Door
Makefile:30: recipe for target 'step1.native' failed
make: *** [step1.native] Error 2
```

I have to compile using both ocamlc and ocamlopt and the executable has to be in the root of the repository.

What am I missing?

Comment: You need `-I step1` to `OCAMLFLAGS` I guess.

Comment: I see, it does work now but it does not create a 'step1' executable (but only creates a .byte and .native)

Comment: Apparently it refuses to do a `cp step1.native` into a `step1` because the repository already has this name.

Comment: You certainly can't have a file and a directory with the same name in the same directory.